# How to make a timer command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I want to make a timer command.

```
    @commands.command()
    async def timer(self, ctx, seconds):
        try:
            secondint = int(seconds)
            if secondint > 300:
                await ctx.send("I dont think im allowed to do go above 300 seconds.")
                raise BaseException
            if secondint < 0 or secondint == 0:
                await ctx.send("I dont think im allowed to do negatives")
                raise BaseException
            message = await ctx.send("Timer: " + seconds)
            while True:
                secondint = secondint - 1
                if secondint == 0:
                    await message.edit(new_content=("Ended!"))
                    break
                await message.edit(new_content=("Timer: {0}".format(secondint)))
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await ctx.send(ctx.message.author.mention + " Your countdown Has ended!")
        except ValueError:
            await ctx.send("Must be a number!")
```

I tried this but this doesn't work , it doesn't edit message like I want it to and no errors.

Comment: Just putting this here, but that is a very bad way to implement a timer since it will hold up the whole thread and is actively waiting. Future viewers of this question, please look into [tasks.loop](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=task#discord.ext.tasks.loop) and [discord tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't edit the message since `new_content` isn't a [`Message.edit()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=edit#discord.Message.edit) method argument.
It only has: content / embed / suppress / delete_after / allowed_mentions.

The one you're looking for is `content`:

```py
@commands.command()
async def timer(self, ctx, seconds):
    try:
        secondint = int(seconds)
        if secondint > 300:
            await ctx.send("I dont think im allowed to do go above 300 seconds.")
            raise BaseException
        if secondint <= 0:
            await ctx.send("I dont think im allowed to do negatives")
            raise BaseException
        message = await ctx.send("Timer: {seconds}")
        while True:
            secondint -= 1
            if secondint == 0:
                await message.edit(content="Ended!")
                break
            await message.edit(content=f"Timer: {secondint}")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Your countdown Has ended!")
    except ValueError:
        await ctx.send("Must be a number!")
```

Answer (score 3):

Alright, so here's a modified version of that script above marked with the green checkmark. I made some changes to make it more user-friendly (unit converter which converts for example "5m" to 300 seconds, and instead of displaying say, "90 seconds" it would display "1 minute 30 seconds" etc.), and easier for the general public to use. I'm not that great at coding, I'm at a beginners level, but I hope this helps!

```py
@commands.command()
async def timer(self, ctx, timeInput):
    try:
        try:
            time = int(timeInput)
        except:
            convertTimeList = {'s':1, 'm':60, 'h':3600, 'd':86400, 'S':1, 'M':60, 'H':3600, 'D':86400}
            time = int(timeInput[:-1]) * convertTimeList[timeInput[-1]]
        if time > 86400:
            await ctx.send("I can\'t do timers over a day long")
            return
        if time <= 0:
            await ctx.send("Timers don\'t go into negatives :/")
            return
        if time >= 3600:
            message = await ctx.send(f"Timer: {time//3600} hours {time%3600//60} minutes {time%60} seconds")
        elif time >= 60:
            message = await ctx.send(f"Timer: {time//60} minutes {time%60} seconds")
        elif time < 60:
            message = await ctx.send(f"Timer: {time} seconds")
        while True:
            try:
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
                time -= 5
                if time >= 3600:
                    await message.edit(content=f"Timer: {time//3600} hours {time %3600//60} minutes {time%60} seconds")
                elif time >= 60:
                    await message.edit(content=f"Timer: {time//60} minutes {time%60} seconds")
                elif time < 60:
                    await message.edit(content=f"Timer: {time} seconds")
                if time <= 0:
                    await message.edit(content="Ended!")
                    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Your countdown Has ended!")
                    break
            except:
                break
    except:
        await ctx.send(f"Alright, first you gotta let me know how I\'m gonna time **{timeInput}**....")
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way it works is if you do something like this

```
import asyncio

@client.command()
async def count(ctx, number:int):
    try:
        if number < 0:
            await ctx.send('number cant be a negative')
        elif number > 300:
            await ctx.send('number must be under 300')
        else:
            message = await ctx.send(number)
            while number != 0:
                number -= 1
                await message.edit(content=number)
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await message.edit(content='Ended!')

    except ValueError:
        await ctx.send('time was not a number')
```